# UIImageView inside UIVisualEffectView - vibrancy not applied

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder, uivisualeffectview, uivibrancyeffect

I'm currently designing a custom view class, such that:

- it is placed upon some contents, blurring them
- it contains some images and labels and vibrancy effect should be applied to them

So the following hierarchy is built in Interface Builder:

[image]

Both the `Visual Effect View`s are placed using `Visual Effect Views with Blur and Vibrancy` in Xcode object library, and a `UILabel` and an `UIImageView` are placed inside `contentView` of the second `Visual Effect View`.

Problem is that the vibrancy effect is not applied to both contents, only `UILabel` has vibrancy, `UIImageView` is not, such as the following screenshot.

[image]

Is there some additional settings I missed, or the vibrancy effect provided by Apple is only available for `UILabel`?

Comment: Is the image a template image?

Comment: @matt Nope, and by setting rendering mode to alwaysTemplate, it worked like a charm. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

The vibrancy effect only works for views that obey the `tintColor`. If you want your image view to have vibrancy, you must be using a template image.

Comment: You are my god.